# I come bearing another Riley

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is a family member, my infix is my path,
>
> My suffix is what witches do, if you incur their wrath

**Tell me what am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are

> Broadcast/ Broadcasting

My prefix is a family member,

> Bro = Brother

my infix is my path,

> Road

My suffix is what witches do, if you incur their wrath

> Cast/ Casting (a spell)

Comment: and you got it again, three in a row now.. :D